# GHC - Linking errors when compiling projects with the ncurses-0.2 library

Tags: haskell, linker-errors, ncurses

I'm trying to use the ncurses-0.2 library from hackage, however whenever I'm trying to compile my project with cabal. I get a linker error, steps of installation + execution following

I'm on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and using the Haskell Platform 2010.02

Do you have any insights or suggestions to solve this issue?

```
$ brew install ncursesw --universal
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with MacPorts and Fink are known to cause problems.
If you experience issues try uninstalling these tools.
==> Downloading http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.7.tar.gz
File already downloaded and cached to /Users/roman/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --prefix=/Users/roman/.homebrew/Cellar/ncursesw/5.7 --mandir=/Users/roman/.homebrew/Cellar/ncursesw/5.7/share/man --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --e
==> make install
/Users/roman/.homebrew/Cellar/ncursesw/5.7: 2734 files, 14M, in 93 seconds

$ cabal install ncurses --extra-include-dirs=/Users/roman/.homebrew/include --extra-lib-dirs=/Users/roman/.homebrew/lib --reinstall
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring ncurses-0.2...
Preprocessing library ncurses-0.2...
Building ncurses-0.2...
[1 of 4] Compiling UI.NCurses.Enums ( dist/build/UI/NCurses/Enums.hs, dist/build/UI/NCurses/Enums.o )
[2 of 4] Compiling UI.NCurses.Types ( UI/NCurses/Types.hs, dist/build/UI/NCurses/Types.o )
[3 of 4] Compiling UI.NCurses       ( dist/build/UI/NCurses.hs, dist/build/UI/NCurses.o )
[4 of 4] Compiling UI.NCurses.Panel ( dist/build/UI/NCurses/Panel.hs, dist/build/UI/NCurses/Panel.o )

UI/NCurses/Panel.chs:49:0:
    Warning: The import of `UI.NCurses' is redundant
               except perhaps to import instances from `UI.NCurses'
             To import instances alone, use: import UI.NCurses()
Registering ncurses-0.2...
Installing library in /Users/roman/.cabal/lib/ncurses-0.2/ghc-6.12.3
Registering ncurses-0.2...

$ cabal build
Preprocessing executables for TicTacToe-0.1...
Building TicTacToe-0.1...
Linking dist/build/TicTacToe/TicTacToe ...
ld: warning: in /Users/roman/.homebrew/lib/libncursesw.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols:
  "_start_color", referenced from:
      _s9ZP_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wget_wch", referenced from:
      _sfkI_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wenclose", referenced from:
      _s9Fs_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_beep", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep2_closure, _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep1_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep3_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep2_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep3_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep1_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep1_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep3_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep2_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_beep_closure )
  "_echo", referenced from:
      _sc50_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___hscore_echo)
  "_can_change_color", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_canDefineColor1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_init_color", referenced from:
      _s97K_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scw2_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wnoutrefresh", referenced from:
      _s2JC_info in NCurses.o
      _scSh_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_noraw", referenced from:
      _scaE_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wtouchln", referenced from:
      _sd53_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _sd53_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wcolor_set", referenced from:
      _sav6_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_meta", referenced from:
      _s9KC_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scV2_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_runCurses2_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _stdscr$non_lazy_ptr in NCurses.o
      _stdscr$non_lazy_ptr in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _stdscr$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_wbkgrndset", referenced from:
      _scOA_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_raw", referenced from:
      _scaE_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _ffi_closure_raw_SYSV$non_lazy_ptr, _ffi_closure_raw_SYSV , _ffi_raw_call , _ffi_prep_raw_closure_loc )
  "__nc_has_mouse", referenced from:
      _hsncurses_has_mouse in libHSncurses-0.2.a(hsncurses-shim.o)
  "_wtimeout", referenced from:
      _s9KE_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scV4_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _sfkG_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_doupdate", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_render1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_baudrate", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate1_info, _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate3_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate2_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate2_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate1_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate3_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate1_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate2_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_baudrate3_srt )
  "_whline_set", referenced from:
      _s9gs_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wvline_set", referenced from:
      _s9fL_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_cbreak", referenced from:
      _s9ZJ_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _sc7P_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_endwin_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_endwin_info, _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_endwin_closure )
  "_wattr_on", referenced from:
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saal_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_newwin", referenced from:
      _s9du_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_getmouse", referenced from:
      _sfkP_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_touchwin", referenced from:
      _sa69_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_untouchwin", referenced from:
      _sa6c_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_has_colors", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_supportsColor1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _s9ZN_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_mousemask", referenced from:
      _s9ZL_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_use_default_colors", referenced from:
      _s9ZS_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_waddwstr", referenced from:
      _sduP_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wmove", referenced from:
      _sdBo_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_dupwin", referenced from:
      _scTH_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_keypad", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_zdwa3_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _say8_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _say8_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scV0_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_noecho", referenced from:
      _sc50_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_flash", referenced from:
      _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash1_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash1_closure, _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash1_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash2_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash3_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash1_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash2_srt , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash2_closure , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash3_info , _ncurseszm0zi2_UIziNCurses_flash3_srt )
  "_wborder_set", referenced from:
      _scFt_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_COLS", referenced from:
      _COLS$non_lazy_ptr in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _COLS$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_init_pair", referenced from:
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saTg_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _scdx_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_nocbreak", referenced from:
      _sc7P_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_delwin", referenced from:
      _sb4T_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_getcurx", referenced from:
      _s9Iy_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_getcury", referenced from:
      _s9Ix_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_color_content", referenced from:
      _sff4_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_COLOR_PAIRS", referenced from:
      _COLOR_PAIRS$non_lazy_ptr in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _COLOR_PAIRS$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_wattr_get", referenced from:
      _s9vO_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wattr_off", referenced from:
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
      _saaF_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_wattr_set", referenced from:
      _s9vS_info in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
  "_LINES", referenced from:
      _LINES$non_lazy_ptr in libHSncurses-0.2.a(NCurses.o)
     (maybe you meant: _LINES$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your question has been [answered already on Haskell Cafe](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3cAANLkTimRkiaTEQm7t3s6irUzz6fSDVGwnQsHGS4AWaiE%40mail.gmail.com%3e).  That's the problem with cross-posting… so please don't.

Comment: Aye, cross-posting is bad form. But I figure I'm more likely to find an answer if I ask in different fora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questions was answered in Haskell-Café

The link:

http://groups.google.com/group/haskell-cafe/browse_thread/thread/b021f338ed2ba738#

Comment: Details within the question are answered by Haskell Cafe, but the most recent post concludes "I'm not sure what
the equivalent would be for homebrew." This does NOT answer my question. In fact, it reiterates it. Q? -> Q.

Comment: Tried it. The x64 version creates even more problems for Mac OS X.